# touchesBegan: inside UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview

I need to implement a drag and drop feature for a UIView added as a subview of UITableViewCell. I catch the drag according to MoveMe example from Apple by using touchesBegan: touchesMoved: events.

This is the view that is added inside the cell:

[image]

The gradientview is the subview of the cell. I need to move the white rectangles only (white boxes are the subviews of the orange-blue gradient view). My problem is that after a few pixels of upward or downward dragging the tableview starts to scroll. Horizontaly it is OK. Seems that the tableView catches the drag after a certain amount of drag. I need to prevent the vertical scroll until the drag is ongoing.

Is there a solution to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

OK. I ended up using UIPanGestureRecognizer. That seems to block tableview underneath.

```
- (void)move:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*) recognizer {
CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self];
[recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self];
recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                     recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
```

}